# spring thymeleaf static content HTTP 405

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, gradle, thymeleaf

I am working with spring boot an thymeleaf and try to get an image from the application.

```
   <img th:src="@{/static/img/png-test.png}"/>
```

this is my tag in my template file. which gets rendered to

```
<img src="/static/img/png-test.png">
```

I already tried to add my own ResourceHandler

```
  @Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
}
```

which seems to work because on startup I get the following message

```
2017-08-04 20:16:02.926  INFO 15234 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/static/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
```

but there is no image showing up inside the browser. instead I get the following error in the browser console

> GET http://localhost:8080/static/img/png-test.png 405 ()

Spring logs the following

```
2017-08-04 19:59:20.265  WARN 14705 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'GET' not supported
```

EDIT:
Could it be a problem that i added this to my `build.gradle` file

```
jar {
    from('src/main/') {
        include 'static/'

    }
}
```

because otherwise gradle never put the static folder into the jar

EDIT:
I found out what is needed to reproduce the failure

I have a function inside my controller which looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(name = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String func(@RequestParam(name = "var1") String var1, @RequestParam(name = "var2") String var2){
    return "templatename";
}
```

When I uncomment the function I am able to receive static content.
at least method not allowed makes sense now. because it is expecting a POST.

So how can I fix this without having to remap the function?

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to create a custom resource handler, because Spring Boot MVC serves static resources by default. What annotations do you have on your main application class? Some annotations disable autoconfiguration of static resources. [This post](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) from the Spring team might provide some useful info.

Comment: my main application class has the `@SpringBootApplication` and `@ComponentScan` anotation

Comment: I can't address the gradle question because I only use maven. Just to be clear, you are putting your static files in directory `your_app_folder/src/main/resources/static`, right?

Comment: i tried it but this lead to the same error. so i put it into `src/main/static`

Comment: Does your application.properties file have a `server.servlet-path` setting? Are there any thymeleaf properties defined in application.properties? If so, please post them. I suspect we are overlooking something obvious. In fact, please post any configuration classes too.

Comment: No I don't have any settings or additional properties I really appreciate your help. But its midnight over here. I will upload my whole project to GitHub tomorrow. So you can have a look at it then.

Comment: Sounds like a plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed that i was just stupid. 
i wrote

`@RequestMapping(name = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)`

instead of

`@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)`

over a function in my controller. which mapped this function to `/**` So my requests to any static content was routed to this function which only accepted the `POST` method.

But still a big thnx to @Kirby

Comment: Thank you for your help. It sounds like a joke but in my project, a "name" instead of "value" mistake somewhat disabled the static resources mapping.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Spring Boot will serve static resources from either `your_app_dir/srce/main/resources/static` or `your_app_dir/srce/main/resources/public`. If you are putting your static resources elsewhere, move the static resources into one of these directories and you should be good to go.

Comment: i know that it should be like that. but it leads to the same error.

Comment: Are you using Spring Security? If so, how is it set up? I ask because HTTP status code 405 "Method not allowed" sounds more like a privileges problem than a case of Spring not finding the static resource.

Comment: No I am not using spring security.

Comment: If your image is at `your_app/src/main/resources/static/img/png-test.png`, the path in the img tag should be `src="/img/png-test.png"`.

Comment: Does any class have the @EnableWebMvc annotation? If so, remove it: the annotation disables some of Spring Boot's autoconfiguration behavior, as described [here](https://techblog.bozho.net/spring-boot-enablewebmvc-common-use-cases/).

Comment: No not anymore.

Comment: i edited the questions. i think the method not allowed makes more sense now.

Comment: I saw the update. The errors occur on a POST to / ? I don't follow. Please provide enough code to replicate the error or describe the specific chain of events that leads to the error.